# Angular4 Material mdmenu

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I am trying on use nested Angular4-Material menu (md-menu). The example online - https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview - is as below:

```
    <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="animals">Animal index</button>
    <md-menu #animals="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="vertebrates">Vertebrates</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="invertebrates">Invertebrates</button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu #vertebrates="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="fish">Fishes</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="amphibians">Amphibians</button>
      <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="reptiles">Reptiles</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Birds</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Mammals</button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu #invertebrates="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Insects</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Molluscs</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Crustaceans</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Corals</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Arachnids</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Velvet worms</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Horseshoe crabs</button>
    </md-menu>
```

My menu data comes from nested JSON - parent child grandchild scenario (L1, L2 and L3 menu). And when I tried to do it with my nested JSON data, I get error as cannot read the L3 menu.

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active" *ngFor="let x of navData">
            <button md-button class="nav-link" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="l2">{{x.name}}</button>
            <md-menu #l2="mdMenu">
                <button md-menu-item *ngFor="let y of x.l2" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="l3">{{y.title}}</button>
            </md-menu>
            <md-menu #l3="mdMenu">
                <button md-menu-item *ngFor="let z of y.l3">{{z}}</button>
            </md-menu>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

It seems "md-menu" doesn't maintain parent-child hierarchy. Any help on this issue please?

Regards and thanks in advance.

---

JSON DATA is like this [ { "name": "Hub" }, { "name": "Workspace", "l2": [ { "title": "Organisation", "l3": [ "hierarchy", "cost-centers", "enterprise-onboarding", "users", "roles", "policies-standards", "environment-type" ] }, { "title": "Resources", "l3": [ "providers-management", "accounts", "metric-provider", "provider-roles", "resource-classification", "resource-management", "images", "template", "config-management", "provider-locations", "provider-template" ] } ] } ]

Comment: Can you include an example of the json file? It is hard to answer a question relating to it without seeing it.

Comment: @tokkov, the JSON DATA is like this [ { "name": "Hub" }, { "name": "Workspace", "l2": [ { "title": "Organisation", "l3": [ "hierarchy", "cost-centers", "enterprise-onboarding", "users", "roles", "policies-standards", "environment-type" ] }, { "title": "Resources", "l3": [ "providers-management", "accounts", "metric-provider", "provider-roles", "resource-classification", "resource-management", "images", "template", "config-management", "provider-locations", "provider-template" ] } ] } ]